# Symfony reusable services

Tags: symfony, service, bundle

Everyone talks about reusable bundles in symfony, but what about reusable services? Should they be easily reusable? Should they sometimes not? I was just thinking about moving some services outside of my bundle and put it directly into /src/services. For example I have a syntax parser that has been in the ForumBundle before, but now I want to use it in another bundle too.

But then I thought, it might be also used in other projects, isn't that common because services should be less coupled because they are simpler than bundles?

Sometimes Iam even unsure if my service shouldn't become a complete bundle, how can I seperate the tasks of this two methods?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think what you might need is to answer with `yes` when using `generate:bundle` console command:

```
$ php app/console generate:bundle

Are you planning on sharing this bundle across multiple applications? [no]: yes
Your application code must be written in bundles. This command helps you generate them easily.

Each bundle is hosted under a namespace (like Acme/BlogBundle). The namespace should begin with a "vendor" name like your company name, your project name, or your client name, followed by one or more optional category sub-namespaces, and it should end with the bundle name itself (which must have Bundle as a suffix).

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name for more details on bundle naming conventions.

Use / instead of \  for the namespace delimiter to avoid any problem.
```

And then declare your services inside this new created bundle, and then, inside another app you might have, if you're making use of the new created bundle, means you automatically use those services too.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look at the structure of open source libraries and bundles.

For example, `KnpMenuBundle` is one of the most popular bundles.
It depends on `KnpMenu` library, which has all the business logic: neсessary classes and methods, templates, etc.
`KnpMenu` library can be used without `KnpMenuBundle`.

The bundle is only the wrapper or bridge between library and symfony application, where you register services, configure it and bind with libraries